# Show that $\frac{1}{n^{\frac{n+1}{n}}}$ decreases

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, induction

How can one show that $\frac{1}{n^{\frac{n+1}{n}}}$ decreases?  I am using this to show that $\Sigma\frac{1}{n^{\frac{n+1}{n}}} $ diverges using Cauchy's condensation test.

Comment: Well, the derivative of $x^{-\frac{x+1}{x}}$ is $x^{-\frac{3x+1}{x}}(\log(x)-x-1)$. Now you just use the fact that $\log(x) < x+1$ for all $x > 0$.

Comment: this is the derivative of $\frac{1}{n^{\frac{n+1}{n}}}$ : $n^{-\frac{1}{n}-3} (-n+\log (n)-1)$ , is it obvious that $\frac{1}{n^{\frac{n+1}{n}}}$ is decreasing ?

Comment: How about without derivatives?

Answer (score 2):

If you know it decreases, then
$$ \varphi(n) \text{ is decreasing } \iff \varphi_{n+1} \leq \varphi_n$$

that is,

$$ (n+1)^{\frac{n+2}{n+1}} \geq n^{\frac{1+n}{n}}$$
can you take it from here? (**hint**: $\log\varphi_{n+1}\geq \log\varphi_n$)

Comment: How about without logarithms?

Comment: @HBHSU Do you _have_ to use a specific criteria? You'd better off tell us.

Comment: I would like to prove it directly or by induction.

Comment: I obtain $n(n+2)log(n+1)>(n+1)(n+1)log(n)$, but I do not know how to show that this is true (so that I can then reverse the argument to prove the statement).

Answer (score -1):

If we look at the exponent in the expression: $\frac{n+1}{n}$, this simplifies to $1 + \frac{1}{n}$.

We clearly see that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$, which means the exponent is just $1 + 0 = 1$.

Then $\frac{1}{n^{\frac{n+1}{n}}}$ becomes $\frac{1}{n^{1}} = \frac{1}{n}$. But we already know what happens with $\frac{1}{n}$ when $n\to\infty$.

Thus giving you: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\frac{n+1}{n}}} = 0$$

As the expression approaches $0$ when $n\to\infty$, it obviously decreases. Then use that fact in Cauchy's condensation test.

Comment: Not sure limits work like that...?

Comment: Just using simple substitution. If you're wondering about $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$, it's used quite often to showcase the definition of a limit.

Comment: That $a_n \to 0$ does not imply that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n $ converges.

Comment: I didn't say that the sum converges. I said that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$ obviously decreases as $n$ increases, that's not the same thing. The original poster said that HE wanted to prove, given that the expression he mentioned decreases (my proof), that the sum of said terms to $\infty$ diverges.